# For whats this "1342177280" flag for?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

I have some code snippet for opening whatsapp with some flags as bellow

```
  Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClassName("com.whatsapp", "com.whatsapp.HomeActivity");
            intent.addFlags(1342177280);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 9);
```

Above snippet showing error on 1342177280 as bellow

[Error image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0k31.png)

I don't understand that whats this flag 1342177280 about , Any idea ?

Comment: These are flags OR'ed together (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#addFlags(int)); 1010000000000000000000000000000 in binary. (Maybe: FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY)

Comment: The warning is because you are using an explicit integer rather than drawing on the 'approved' list of flags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm extending on codebod's comment

> The warning is because you are using an explicit integer rather than drawing on the 'approved' list of flags.

Intent's addFlags() method takes an int parameter that are predefined in the android framework as constants. The predefined constants have corresponding integer value. You are seeing that error as the integer value you entered doesn't match with any of the predefined values.

Check [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent?authuser=3#addFlags(int)) documentation to see the list of valid parameters Intent's addFlags() method can accept.